# Screen bounds extends visible area

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm trying to make a square (50 x 50) UIView in the lower right hand of my main view, but I'm confused about why it's not entirely visible. In this instance, only the tip of it is visible from the bottom. Am I confusing some concept?

> ```
>     CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
>     CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);
>     UIView *transparentFloater = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width - 50.f, height - 50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
>
>     [self.view addSubview:transparentFloater];
> ```

Comment: sorry , what is your problem i can not got it ..

Comment: according to my logic, there should be a 50x50 UIView on the bottom right of the parent view, but for some reason, it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the autoresizing mask:

```
transparentFloater.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Comment: I think that code you have provided is in viewDidLoad. And size of view in xib file is different that on device. So after viewDidLoad view have changed it's frame. Autoresizing masks help keep view in the bottom right corner.

Comment: yes the code is in face in viewdidload, is there a better area to keep it?

Comment: No. I think it's ok. But you should always remember that view can change its size. So you should not forget about autoresizing masks ( or constraints ) when you add subview.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, You have created your ViewController with xib and in the attributes of view, you have forgot to mention that you are using a "**navigation bar**" as "**top bar**".

**Reason**

So in ViewDidLoad, view in .xib with a height **X** is returned. But as you might have loaded the viewController using **UINavigationController**, after loading the height of view is decreased by **44pixels**.

**Suggestions** :

1) Whenever you know that you are going to have **navigation bar** on top please mention it in **.xib** file as well.

For doing so click on the view in xib and select the option called **topbar** in **attributes Inspector** of **utilities area**

2) Call the following api

```
    NSLog(@"In ViewDidAppear %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
```

in

- viewDidLoad
- viewDidAppear

  to track whats happening with the bounds of view

Answer (score 0):

You does not need to do anything just put

```
transparentFloater.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

because your view (custom) is invisible (because your main view color and custom view color are same ***(white)*** ) may be. I tried your code in my demo project. it worked perfectly for me.